# cordova navigator.connection.type is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm making a hybrid HTML5 applications using cordova. events such as `deviceready` and `backbutton` all running correctly. but when the event `navigator.connection.type` in execution, the event does not work correctly. Here is the code

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/js/cordova.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
   function onLoad(){
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
   }

   function onDeviceReady() {
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButton, false);
       checkConnection();
   }

   function checkConnection() {
       alert("test");  // first alert. Work

       var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
       var states = {};
       states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
       states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
       states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
       states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

       alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);  // second alert
   }

   function onBackButton() {
       // code
   }
</script>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <!-- code -->
</body>
```

I use two alerts, the first alert works well while the second alert is not working. I've added a plugin `cordova plugin add-plugin-network-information` to my app using node.js command prompt too. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any specific errors? Does `navigator.connection.type` generate any errors?

Comment: i tried to run my apk app on android. so i don't know, how to see the error log. have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that onload function.
Its more than likely calling your checkConnection function too soon.

Just try this;

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function checkConnection() {
   alert("test");  // first alert. Work

   var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
   var states = {};

   states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
   states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
   states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
   states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
   states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

   alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);  // second alert
 }


function onDeviceReady() {
  checkConnection();
}
```

And cordova will handle the onDeviceReady

Comment: same as before, the second alert still does not appear.